# compiler error calling a private sub procedure

Tags: vba, excel

```
    Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange _
     (ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
     x = Sh.UsedRange.Rows.Count
End Sub
```

I have a private sub procedure like this and I am trying to call it by

```
 Workbook_SheetSelectionChange _
```

and I am getting a compiling error, i tried to rename the sub but it doesn't let me delete the underscore because of the second line in the sub. I wonder why that is and how can i call this sub?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `_` is a line continuation character

```
 Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange (ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
```

is the same as

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange _
 (ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
```

which is the same as (taken to extremes)

```
Private _
Sub _
Workbook_SheetSelectionChange _
(ByVal _
Sh _
As _
Object, _
ByVal _
Target _
As _
Excel.Range)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try simply:

`Workbook_SheetSelectionChange`

Or

`Call Workbook_SheetSelectionChange`

The `_` is a continuation character, **not** part of the subroutine's name.